# std::iterator_traits for integral types in Microsoft standard library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, specifications

I have a template function, that needs to be specialized for iterators. So what I did was along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
void function2(T whatever, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer) // ... iterator

template <typename T>
void function2(T whatever, ...) // ... non-iterator

template <typename T>
void function(T whatever) {
    function2(whatever, NULL);
}
```

And I've hit a wall, because Microsoft standard library specializes `std::iterator_traits` for all numeric types (`bool`, `char`, `int`, `float`…). And it does it so that `reference` and `pointer` are non-`void`, despite the fact that neither `operator*` nor `operator->` can be called on those types.

Ok, I can checki the `std::iterator_traits<T>::category` derives `std::input_iterator` (actually I think `std::forward_iterator` is more appropriate in my case) at the cost of some more complex template machinery.

I would however be interested in knowing:

- Why do they define `iterator_traits` for types, that don't conform to the iterator concept (even output iterators need at least unary `operator*`, none of these types have one.
- Are they violating C++ specification in doing so? Not that Microsoft wouldn't be violating it all over the place, but if they are I would be satisfied with compiler-specific workaround, if they don't obviously not.
- And is it even workable in general anyway? It appears the `std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer` always exists, but is undefined and that leads to error rather than SFINAE.

Comment: Aside: your code is invalid C++ (but MSVC will accept it), you need to mark the dependent name `std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer` by `typename`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks. I am actually compiling in both msvc++ and gcc 4.5 and 4.6, so I need to have those in, but it was not copy-paste; the actual code takes a template specialized on something and I am checking whether that something is iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Other functions [res.on.functions]**
>
> [...]
>
> 2 In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template component, if the operations on
>     the type do not implement the semantics of the applicable Requirements subclause

In order to use `iterator_traits<T>`, `T` must be an iterator. If it isn't, the behaviour is undefined. You cannot detect whether a type `T` is an iterator at compile time. It is not even theoretically possible, since a type is allowed to support the same operators and typedefs as iterators, so that an implementation's generic `iterator_traits<T>` can be instantiated without any error or warning message, but with a completely different meaning.

Thinking about it, since your comment clarifies that a reasonable guess is good enough, I think you're best off using SFINAE and `enable_if` to detect core operations (unary `*` and prefix `++`), using `std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer` only if those conditions are met.

Comment: Well, I doubt any type would define `::iterator_category` and still not actually be iterator, so for practical purpose that should work.

Comment: "In order to use iterator_traits<T>, T must be an iterator" -- where does the standard say that? The concept requirements for algorithms come from 25.1/5, but I can't find anything to say that `Iterator` is likewise a special template parameter name. I agree with you that just because `iterator_traits<T>` instantiates doesn't mean the type `T` is an iterator, though, so the main point of your answer holds either way.

Comment: I would create such a type in my own code for fun, just to mess with yours, but that's just me. :) Yes, if you don't need to worry about such types, there are some things you can do.

Comment: @SteveJessop Since iterator_traits is defined in 24.4.1, I believe 24.2 Iterator requirements applies.

Comment: @hvd: can you be more specific which part of 24.2 you mean? I don't see how the statements in 24.2, "iterators have the following properties..." imply what you say they imply, "the `Iterator` template parameter of `iterator_traits` must be an iterator`. Iterator types are required to have a suitable `iterator_traits` specialization. The way I read 24.4.1/2 is a guarantee that for any type `Iterator`, if it has all those nested types then the catch-all `iterator_traits` template will provide the necessary specialization. No more or less.

Comment: @SteveJessop 24.2.2, "A type `X` satisfies the `Iterator` requirements if:" combined with the fact that 17.6.4.8 simply refers to "the applicable *Requirements* subclause". The standard doesn't actually spell it out beyond that, but I don't see how it can reasonably be interpreted otherwise.

Comment: @hvd: put it another way: if this requirement on `iterator_traits` goes without saying, then what's the purpose of the text in 25.1/5? Why doesn't all that likewise go without saying?

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure, other than that otherwise, an argument could be made that 24.2 isn't the "applicable" Requirements subclause, since 24.2 isn't part of 25. I think you're right, by the way, that the standard may guarantee that `iterator_traits` can be instantiated for some (not all) non-iterator types that pretend to be iterators.

Comment: Anyway, I've upvoted your answer because one cannot use the existence of `iterator_traits<T>` as "proof" that `T` is an iterator. But I still don't see the requirement you do, that the `Iterator` argument is an iterator. If the standard wanted to require that, then I think clause 24 would contain text similar to that in 25.1/5, stating that the name of the parameter implies that it satisfies the corresponding requirements. One could perhaps even say that the standard *requires* `iterator_traits<int>` to fail to instantiate due to the non-existence of `int::pointer`.

Comment: I think the problem is a circular definition. If the standard made the requirement you think it does, then anyone defining nested types in their iterator, relying on the catch-all `iterator_traits` to ensure that their type satisfies the iterator requirements, would be in the position that their type satisfies the iterator requirements (what they're trying to achieve) if and only if it satisfies the iterator requirements (pre-condition of the catch-all template definition). This would be unsatisfactory to me if not to the authors ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, that's one I read the other way around: a functional `iterator_traits` isn't part of the iterator requirements, because it isn't part of 24.2. Therefore, a type without a custom `iterator_traits` can meet the iterator requirements, which then requires the generic `iterator_traits` to do the right thing. But I think I see your point, this is not at all as clear as I initially thought.

Comment: @hvd: indeed, there's some slightly strange text organization there. 24.4.1 quite clearly says, "it is required that if `Iterator` is the type of an iterator, then [there's a functioning `iterator_traits`]". That's not part of the "Iterator Requirements" gathered together in 24.2, but it is an unconditional requirement made by the standard on all iterators. An example of the fact that any sentence anywhere in the standard can impose a requirement on any program construct. But I now see what you're saying: it can be read as breaking the cycle in my "circular" definition.

Comment: @SteveJessop: But it's important that the opposite implication does not hold. There is no requirement that if something isn't iterator, it does not have iterator traits.

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't need the `pointer` trait at all and I don't really need to cover all cases. It's just for logging, so I'll just replicate the two base cases (pointers and types with `iterator_category` subtype).

Comment: Just spotted more on iterator requirements. 24.4.4/4 says for `std::distance` "If InputIterator meets the requirements of random access iterator, returns `(last-first)`". This is only possible to implement if the `iterator_traits` and in particular the category are part of "the iterator requirements". Of course, it could still be that they very cleverly worded the iterator requirements separately from the traits, but then forgot all about that by the time they came to specifying the iterator functions...

Comment: @SteveJessop I think that's essentially the same argument as before: my view on that is that if a type is an iterator, then `iterator_traits` is required (that's a requirement in part on implementations and in part on users) to report the correct `iterator_category` separately from "the iterator requirements". :)

Comment: @SteveJessop Related but slightly different: just yesterday, I got confused by [sequence.reqmts]p14 "If the constructor [...] is called with a type `InputIterator` that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.", but that is followed by p15 "The extent to which an implementation determines that a type cannot be an input iterator is unspecified, except that as a minimum integral types shall not qualify as input iterators."